# Merge columns and add

Tags: text-processing, awk, columns, merge

I have a file with the following content (there are additional spaces to pad the first column)

```
  1 account1 192.168.0.1  
  1 account1 192.168.0.2   
 19 account2 192.168.0.1   
100 account3 192.168.0.3   
  1 account3 192.168.0.5
```

And I am trying to get to an output of

```
  2 account1 192.168.0.1, 192.168.0.2  
 19 account2 192.168.0.1  
101 account3 192.168.0.3, 192.168.0.5
```

which I will loop through so that I can create an html table to email to an account. I managed to get the list of IPs per account using :

```
awk '{a[$2]=a[$2]" " $3}END{for (i in a) print i" " a[i]}' inputfile
```

but I cannot get to sum the first column as well.

Answer (score 3):

Adding the sum to your script shouldn't be too hard, just add another array to hold it.

```
$ awk '{ if (a[$2]) a[$2] = a[$2] ", ";
         a[$2] = a[$2] $3;
         sum[$2] += $1 }
       END {for (x in a) printf "%3d %s %s\n", sum[x], x, a[x]}' inputfile
  2 account1 192.168.0.1, 192.168.0.2
 19 account2 192.168.0.1
101 account3 192.168.0.3, 192.168.0.5
```

(Your sample output had the IP address separated by commas, so I added that too. Though at least the code is neater without it, in my opinion.)

Answer (score 2):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk 'NR==1{ match($0, /^ +[^ ]+/); s=length(substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)) }
     { sum[$2]+=$1; ips[$2]=($2 in ips? ips[$2]", ":"")$3 }
     END{ 
         for (i in sum) 
             printf("%*s %s %s\n", s, sum[i], i, ips[i]) 
     }' file
```

The output:

```
  2 account1 192.168.0.1, 192.168.0.2
 19 account2 192.168.0.1
101 account3 192.168.0.3, 192.168.0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm probably overthinking this, (there's likely a nice awk/sed to be used) but this is the best thing I can come up with:

```
#!/bin/bash
# set file as sys argument
file=$1

# pull unique account names into an array
account_names=($(awk '{print $2}' $file | sort | uniq))

# loop through and store column values
for account in ${account_names[@]}; do
    # get a sum of the first column
    col1=$(grep $account $file | awk '{SUM += $1} END {print SUM}')
    # get last column and convert to one line with comma separation
    IP_list=$(grep $account $file | awk '{print $NF}' | sort | uniq | tr '\n' ',' | sed s'/.$//')
    # print them together
    echo "$col1 $account $IP_list"
done
```

Then you can run it like so:

```
┌─[robotjohny@Fedora]─[~]─[04:08 pm]
└─[$]› ./test1.sh file1.txt 
2 account1 192.168.0.1,192.168.0.2
19 account2 192.168.0.1
101 account3 192.168.0.3,192.168.0.5
```

Comment: this makes for a very good reusable function, thank you